# Convert Character to Number in Oracle

Tags: oracle, oracle10g, ascii

I have ColumnA in table. The data of each row is single character between A & H.

I want my select query to return 1 for 'A', 2 for B .... 8 for H.

My query always returns only one row. I can make a lookup table.

Anyone has better ideas to achieve the same ?

Comment: How about "select (ascii(ColumnA) - 64) from table"

Comment: Bingo ! i was looking xactly for this but wasnt able to find syntax. Thanks a lot John

Comment: Surely `select ascii(upper(columna)) - 64 from table` to be safe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT 1 + ASCII(columnA) - ASCII('A')
FROM   table
```